# Rails: Either no associated records OR none of the associated records created by aspecific condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

```
class User
   has_many :contacts
end

class Contact
   belongs_to :user
   # id
   # contact_type -> ['main', 'work', 'home']
end
```

What is the cleanest way to get only those users that either don't have any contact OR if they have contacts then none of the `contact_type` value is `main` ?

**Example:**

```
User: id: 1, name: 'Dev'
Contacts: []

User: id: 2, name: 'Mike'
Contacts: [
  id: 1, contact_type: 'work'
  id: 2, contact_type: 'main'
]

User: id: 3, name: 'John'
Contacts: [
  id: 3, contact_type: 'work'
  id: 4, contact_type: 'home'
]
```

**Result:** Should return users with id 1 and 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can left join `users` and `contacts`, group the rows by the `users.id` column, filter the groups without main contacts (using `count` with a `case` statement), and select the columns from the `users` table.

If you're using Rails 5+, you can use [`left_outer_joins`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-left_outer_joins).

```
User
  .left_outer_joins(:contacts)
  .group('users.id')
  .having("count(case when contact_type = 'main' then 1 end) = 0")
```

On older versions, you can pass a SQL fragment to the [`joins`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-joins) method to perform a left join.

```
 User
   .joins('left join contacts on contacts.user_id = users.id')
   .group('users.id')
   .having("count(case when contact_type = 'main' then 1 end) = 0")
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/fb107/1)